# Reverse a string in Python but keep numbers in original order

Tags: python, string

I can reverse a string using the `[::- 1]` syntax. Take note of the example below:

```
text_in = 'I am 25 years old'
rev_text = text_in[::-1]
print rev_text
```

Output:

```
dlo sraey 52 ma I
```

How can I reverse only the letters while keeping the numbers in order?

The desired result for the example is `'dlo sraey 25 ma I'`.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting question. You could make it even better by including one of your own ideas and explain why it did not work out.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an approach with `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> text_in = 'I am 25 years old'
>>> ''.join(s if s.isdigit() else s[::-1] for s in reversed(re.split('(\d+)', text_in)))
'dlo sraey 25 ma I'
>>> 
>>> text_in = 'Iam25yearsold'
>>> ''.join(s if s.isdigit() else s[::-1] for s in reversed(re.split('(\d+)', text_in)))
'dlosraey25maI'
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `split()` and `join()` along with `str.isdigit()` to identify numbers :

```
>>> s = 'I am 25 years old'
>>> s1 = s.split()
>>> ' '.join([ ele if ele.isdigit() else ele[::-1] for ele in s1[::-1] ])
=> 'dlo sraey 25 ma I'
```

**NOTE :** This only works with numbers that are space separated. For others, check out [timegeb's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235807/7550472) answer using `regex`.

Comment: @timgeb : for that case, answer was very similar to [timegeb's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235807/7550472) . So have pointed to that itself.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a step by step approach:

```
text_in = 'I am 25 years old'
text_seq = list(text_in)                          # make a list of characters
text_nums = [c for c in text_seq if c.isdigit()]  # extract the numbers

num_ndx = 0
revers = []
for idx, c in enumerate(text_seq[::-1]):          # for each char in the reversed text
    if c.isdigit():                               # if it is a number
        c = text_nums[num_ndx]                    # replace it by the number not reversed
        num_ndx += 1
    revers.append(c)                              # if not a number, preserve the reversed order
print(''.join(revers))                            # output the final string
```

#### Output :

```
dlo sraey 25 ma I
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in **pythonic** way straight forward like below..

```
def rev_except_digit(text_in):
    rlist = text_in[::-1].split() #Reverse the whole string and split into list

    for i in range(len(rlist)): # Again reverse only numbers
        if rlist[i].isdigit():
            rlist[i] = rlist[i][::-1]
    return ' '.join(rlist)
```

Test:

```
Original: I am 25 years 345 old 290
Reverse: 290 dlo 345 sraey 25 ma I
```

you can find official python doc here [split() and other string methods](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), [slicing[::-1]](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: You claim that this is supposed to be pythonic (in boldface) without explaining why you think so. For starters, `range(len(some_list))` is considered bad style almost all of the time because we have `enumerate`.

Answer (score -1):

```
text = "I am 25 years old"
new_text = ''
text_rev = text[::-1]
for i in text_rev.split():
    if not i.isdigit():
         new_text += i + " ";
    else:
        new_text += i[::-1] + " ";


print(new_text)
```